# Why would INSERT, REPLACE or UPDATE statements sometimes take over 1 second to execute?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, mariadb, performance-tuning

I have a very good server (great CPU, huge RAM, NVMe) with a huge InnoDB buffer pool that's not full yet.
The website is very write-intensive, but it runs fast enough (`SELECT` queries well optimized, good indexes where possible, etc).

However, since I've reduced `long_query_time` to just 1, I've been finding some queries which I'm not sure how I can improve.

- `INSERT` statements that should simply insert the row without any problem;
- `REPLACE` statements that should simply be based on the primary key to replace the row if needed;
- `UPDATE` statements that use the primary key in the `WHERE` clause, and just updates a simple field.

This is the kind of insights I see logged in the Slow Query table:

> Query Time = 00:00:01.842812
> Lock Time = 00:00:00.000081
> Rows Examined = 0
>
> Query Time = 00:00:01.658600
> Lock Time = 00:00:00.000150
> Rows Examined = 0
>
> Query Time = 00:00:01.825054
> Lock Time = 00:00:00.000170
> Rows Examined = 1
>
> Query Time = 00:00:02.241583
> Lock Time = 00:00:00.000084
> Rows Examined = 1

This seems to just be some occurrences during the day, and not all queries of the same type.

My first suspicion would be that the tables might be locked at that point, but the "Lock Time" above is obviously negligible.

All my tables are InnoDB, and:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_doublewrite              = 1
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 95G
innodb_log_file_size            = 24G
open_files_limit                = 10000
```

Replication is disabled. No table partitions. MariaDB 10.8.

Comment: It is possible, for example, that some huge query eliminates the table from the cache. And the server needs re-read the table for the query execution which needs in some time. Does the available memory is enough for to fit all your databases into the cache?

Comment: @Akina - thank you for your reply. What cache exactly are you referring to? Query Cache is disabled, I'm not aware of any other. The buffer pool is not full yet (74.03% used), so there is still room there to fit more data. The server has a lot of memory free still (36GB free).

Comment: To Akina's point, do you have more Memory allocated to the Buffer Pool than the total size of all databases on your server?...just because it's not full now doesn't mean it wasn't at some previous point. Things get flushed from it for different reasons, so the fullness can fluctuate.

Comment: @J.D. - thank you. It's been constantly around the same % (haven't seen it full since I increased to 95GB months ago), even though the database is much larger than that, but a lot of the data is not used daily (or it's archives, etc).

Comment: Are all your tables `ENGINE=InnoDB`?

Comment: Essentially the only "cache" for InnoDB is the buffer_pool.

Comment: When a 96GB buffer_pool has 95GB in it, it is full.  A small amount is kept in reserve.  It sure sounds like some missing indexes.

Comment: Does this happen on multiple tables, or just one table? Do the tables have many secondary indexes? Do the tables have triggers?

Comment: Have you measured I/O contention using `iostat` or similar tool? The time could be spent trying to sync to the innodb redo log, and your write-intensive workload is reaching the limit of your I/O throughput.

Comment: @RickJames - "Are all your tables ENGINE=InnoDB" -- yes - I said in the question :)

Comment: @BillKarwin - Multiple tables. The tables have multiple indexes, like 3 or 4 each (and they're needed). No triggers in the database, at all.

Comment: @BillKarwin - %iowait = 0.00; %idle = 98.06 . It's always around these values. Pretty sure %iowait is mostly always 0.00. Never seen it higher, since I use NVMe.

Comment: [Optimizer trace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizer-trace-guide/) or old school [profile](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-profile/)? If nothing exciting there [performance schema](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/performance-schema/) may help (but I've barely used it).

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, `REPLACE` can and should be replaced by `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

`REPLACE` is a combo of a `DELETE` and an `INSERT`.  If an auto_increment id is being used, it always burns a value, leading the ids rising rapidly.

Where practical, "batch" `INSERTs`.  100 rows can be inserted in a single batch 10 times as fast as one-row-at-a-time.

Poor indexing can lead to unnecessary table scans, which take time *and* block another activity.  Please provide sample `REPLACEs` and `UPDATEs`, plus the relevant `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.

Combine queries where it makes sense.  For example, don't do a `SELECT` to get the PK, just to make the `UPDATE` faster.

1 second for a query tells me one of these:  (`*`) inadequate `INDEX` or (`*`) complex query, or (`*`) some other query is blocking things.  (The "lock time" is not relevant.)

How big are the tables?  A table scan of a million rows would take seconds or maybe minutes, even fully cached.

Comment: Hi Rick. I appreciate your time and reply. However, I'm not sure if any of the above explains the situation. If you see, "Rows Examined = 0 or 1", so I doubt it's an inadequate Index or Full Table Scan happening. :) .. and regarding `REPLACE`, sometimes I do it intentionally. As I said, these seem to be happening randomly. All of these queries run instantly, most of the time.