# In MySQL/MariaDB, do Indexes' performance degrade as they become larger and larger?

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, innodb, partitioning

I'm currently exploring the use of `PARTITION`, for a specific use case I have.
**I use InnoDB, file per table. MariaDB 10.8.**

I was reading Rick's [PARTITION Maintenance in MySQL](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) webpage.

I'd like to highlight this bit:

> `WHERE X = 1234` -- This lets "partition pruning" look only in that one partition. But that's no better than `INDEX(x)` on a non-partitioned table. And you probably need that index anyway; after first 'pruning' down to the desired partition, you still need the index. No faster.
> A common fallacy: "Partitioning will make my queries run faster". It won't. Ponder what it takes for a 'point query'. Without partitioning, but with an appropriate index, there is a BTree (the index) to drill down to find the desired row. For a billion rows, this might be 5 levels deep. With partitioning, first the partition is chosen and "opened", then a smaller BTree (of say 4 levels) is drilled down. Well, the savings of the shallower BTree is consumed by having to open the partition. Similarly, if you look at the disk blocks that need to be touched, and which of those are likely to be cached, you come to the conclusion that about the same number of disk hits is likely. Since disk hits are the main cost in a query, Partitioning does not gain any performance (at least for this typical case). The 2D case (below) gives the main contradiction to this discussion.

I totally understand what it means, but I have a question:

**In MySQL/MariaDB, do Indexes' performance degrade as they become larger and larger?**

For a billion rows, or for 100 billion rows, is a good Index always better than Partitions, in terms of Performance?

--

There is also this bit which is closest to what I'm trying to benefit:

> Use case #3 -- Hot spot. This is a bit complicated to explain. Given this combination:
> ⚈  A table's index is too big to be cached, but the index for one partition is cacheable, and
> ⚈  The index is randomly accessed, and
> ⚈  Data ingestion would normally be I/O bound due to updating the index
> Partitioning can keep all the index "hot" in RAM, thereby avoiding a lot of I/O.
>
> The big win for Case #3: Improving caching to decrease I/O to speed up operations.

Is "index cached" valid for InnoDB too? My understanding is `CACHE INDEX` only applies to MyISAM.
Or does this relate to it being in the InnoDB Buffer Pool?

**And in relation to decreasing I/O, does this apply to NVMe servers? My `%iowait` is 0.00, while my application is write-intensive.**

Comment: Yes, indexes' performance degrade as they become larger and larger. Does it matter? Is it noticeable? Usually not. However, if you randomly delete lots of lines, you index may become fragmented. Usually, that's not an issue with MariaDB/InnoDB, but you try an OPTIMIZE TABLE (which will also rebuild the indexes). Note that this might lock up your database operations until it finishes, so try it on a test machine with production-like data - not just a copy of the data, but with a database which has aged due to real-life-like inserts/deletes. Compare before/after performance.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yep, I'm aware of `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, but it locks the whole table which isn't acceptable. I've tried the Percona Tools, but there is always something with the tables that prevents us from being able to use this tool :) (causing a crash, etc)

Comment: For normal random deletes/updates, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is unlikely to provide more than a trivial improvement.  The fear of fragmentation is mostly a myth in InnoDB.

Comment: @Nuno - Please tell us what type of data you have.  The discussions so far are too general for you to give you many actionable tips.

Comment: Sorry @RickJames, only now I saw your question. It's basically Groups, Posts and Replies. There will always be "random accesses" (due to crawlers or users going back to old posts), but what needs to be "cached" in the pool is mostly the recent posts, to show on the user Feeds :) (the Feeds follow a complex algorithm, friends, relevancy, privacy, blocks, etc - not the same Feed shown to everyone)

Comment: Do you have a billion posts?  One per web page?  Will a crawler read every one of the billion pages?  I doubt if Partitioning would make any difference. as bobflux nicely explains.  The "recent" pages will mostly stay cached in spite of the crawler tending to do otherwise.  Instead...

Comment: @Nuno - (continued) ... I would focus on optimizing the queries.  This may involve schema changes, but Partitioning is unlikely.  Let's see the main queries.  Better yet, run the slowlog with a low `long_query_time` for at least a day to find the "worst" queries.  See [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: And...  I was involved in building a Plugin for WordPress, which [in some cases] more than doubled the speed of generating a page of a Posting.  It was modifications to the indexes for several tables.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames . I do have a `long_query_time=1`, and all is good - just "expected" housekeeping/admin queries appear there. Even though the Feed has a HUUUGE complex query (~51600 chars, believe or not), it runs instantly because it's over-over-over-optimized. Many hours on `EXPLAIN` and `ANALYZE`, after getting alerts of it taking >1s on a number of users in the past. I'm just "afraid" of how it will be when this "great single server" won't be enough..!!! The database is ~200GB and growing. Happy 2023 - thanks for everything!

Comment: Well, and some rare queries that take 1 second when it's not expected :) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319823/why-would-insert-replace-or-update-statements-sometimes-take-over-1-second-to-e

Comment: There is also a quite interesting one appearing in the slow log - just opened a new Question for it - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321609/how-can-i-sort-thousands-of-replies-on-a-post-following-an-algorithm-thats-not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(In addition to Bill's comments...)

Another way to analyze performance -- "Count the disk hits".

- InnoDB caches 16KB blocks (data and index) in its buffer_pool.
- The cache is on-demand and roughly least-recently-used.
- All activity (read, write, lookup, etc) is done in the buffer_pool, not directly on disk.
- A simple Rule of Thumb is that the fanout of any InnoDB BTree is about 100.  (Percona used 128--essentially the same.)  A billion rows (of data or index) will have 5 levels.  That means that 5 blocks must be fetched (if not already cached) to do a simple point-query.  Or 10 blocks for a lookup via a secondary key.  (6 and 12 for 100 billion rows.)
- If you are fetching 101 'consecutive' rows from that BTree, you will need 2 leaf nodes (the one you start with plus the next one.)  Another Rule of Thumb:  All the non-leaf nodes are probably cached.
- If your activity is random (as with a UUID or hash for the PK) *and* the buffer_pool cannot hold the entire BTree, the cache becomes mostly useless.  This leads to each point-query taking at least 1 disk hit.  In this case, "too big is terrible for performance".
- If on the other hand, you are only touching "recent" rows (and the PK is AUTO_INCREMENT or time-based), then the cache buffer_pool has the desired data 99 times out of 100.  That is, there is essentially no degradation as the table grows, even when much bigger than the buffer_pool.

(I did a lot of 'hand-waving' in those last two statements.)

I hope I have given you some clues on how to judge for yourself whether *your* table will or won't suffer as it grows.  If you would like further discussion, please provide the `CREATE TABLE`.  When someone talks about bilion-row tables, I like to shrink datatypes, restructure the schema, normalize, add Summary tables, consider sharding, etc.  But I rarely recommend Partitioning.  Sometimes, I recommend "keep the summary tables, but toss the Fact table."  This eliminates all sorts of scaling and performance problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rick. So far, I've been scaling vertically, but the conclusion I'm taking from the replies here is that Indexes and Partitions on their own will not resolve the scalability issue. Sharding (scaling horizontally) seems to be where this is heading. Something like Vitess or MariaDB CONNECT, from what I'm researching. This obviously brings a number of other headaches & cons.

Comment: I like your suggestion of "keep the summary tables, but toss the Fact table". Does this mean something like moving the "TEXT columns" of the "Posts" table into partitioned/sharded tables split into multiple servers ([ID, TEXT]), but keep the "meta data" table (with all the entries & indexes, without the Text) in just 1 server? This way, this table is a lot smaller in size, can still be used for JOINs and all that stuff, without any performance impact, and then once we have the final result of "Posts" to display to the user, that's when we go fetch the text for each of those posts. Is that it?

Comment: @Nuno I'd be wary of sharing. Doubling the number of server might double the performance, but only in very specific scenarios (like lots of concurrent queries). But in many other cases, a single server with twice the RAM should beat two servers with regular RAM size each. But, naturally, we're all poking around in the dark without SSH access to your database machine. Hint: no, don't post SSH credentials online ;)

Comment: @Klaws - Thank you. I'm already at the "maximum" RAM that my hosting provider supports (128GB), and at the moment it's all good. However, I can't forever scale vertically. At some point, I'll have to go horizontally. I just want to make sure I'm prepared whenever I see signs that I'm reaching the limits! :) I'll email you my SSH key and server IP, give me 1 min.

Comment: @Nuno To add on to what Klaws said, and I think you missed the point a little, but indexes scale very well. Sharding is a big pain (bigger than partitioning IMO), so much so that even databases designed for it like MongoDB actually recommend against using the feature. And rarely do the people who use it, actually need it. As Bill mentioned in his answer a B-Tree index has a search time complexity of `O(log2n)`. That means for a 1 **trillion** row table, in the worst case, only 40 nodes of the B-Tree need to be seeked through to find any data you're searching for. Seeking 40 nodes is...

Comment: ...very fast. My graphing calculator could do that in sub-second time. If your table grew to to 1 **quadrillion rows**, then `log2(1 quadrillion) = 50`. 50 is still really small. Notice how for an order of magnitude in growth of rows, only 10 more nodes need to be seeked on. With properly designed databases, one likely doesn't need 128 GB of Memory, but generally more Memory is good for caching things. But I've worked with tables that had 10s of billions of rows in them on servers with only 8 GB of Memory, and most queries ran in under a second.

Comment: Thanks @J.D. - although it's hard to believe that you had 10s of billions of rows in 8GB RAM server, with most queries running under a second :) - unless the disk was a very good one, if your data isn't in the InnoDB Buffer Pool, there will be disk lookups involved there, and twice, if the indexes aren't "covering indexes". Thanks very much for your advice though!

Comment: @Nuno Well the caveat to my statement is I was using SQL Server, but the idea of caching is similar-enough between the two. The disks were regular SSDs, not even NVMes. The point is, the size of data at rest doesn't matter much from a performance standpoint. If you're only using 8 GB of data in your routine workload, 8 GB of Memory (roughly speaking) is enough. And when data flushed in and out of the cache, the occasional disk lookup for a small subset of data, even on just SSDs, is milliseconds (perhaps less) of time. Eventually we did bump the Memory up to 16 GB per my advisement though.

Comment: @J.D. Ah, there's the rub. Yes, if the _active_ portion of your table fits in the cache, it will all work out. So it depends strongly on the workload pattern. If the table has more or less random access pattern, or if it has table-scans for doing aggregation queries, it's a different story.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, in regards to Memory, indeed. But even uncached data (especially with NVMes these days) takes trivial time to load off disk. The problem most people run into is index scans when the data they need doesn't actually warrant a scan. Scanning the entire index from disk will hurt, with insufficient Memory. But I usually find that being either an architectural problem (improperly designed tables or improperly designed indexes) or a query tuning problem. So usually these are solvable without throwing hardware at it. The only exception is aggregative queries like you mentioned. In...

Comment: ...SQL Server they have columnstore indexes to compress the data up and down the column level, and enable batch mode operations. These hugely improve aggregative queries on large tables. Not sure if MySQL offers a similar feature, but if not, of course there's the classic methodology of pre-aggregating the data in a separate table, that is appropriately maintained.

Comment: @J.D. MySQL itself does not provide a columnstore engine or index type. But it does provide an extensible architecture, and some third-party companies have developed columnstores that can be plugged into MySQL.

Comment: @Nuno - "Fact table" is a Data Warehouse concept; it does not apply to "posts + meta" (a la WordPress) -- The two have radically different scaling issues.  When collecting, for example, meteorological data from thousands of sensors every minute, you don't need to keep all the details.  Hourly summaries may suffice -- and be much smaller.  (Sure, keep the details for a few days, then purge.  And Partitioning is very good for the purging.)

Comment: Sharding is useful when you cannot handle the _write_ volume or the disk space needed.  Replication is useful for _read_ volume.  Clustering is useful for HA (High Availability).  Those 3 techniques can be mixed in _certain_ ways.

Comment: If you have a trillion rows, you need to re-think the entire design.  Toss data you don't really need.  Summarize and toss.  Archive it as compressed plain text.  Etc, etc.

Comment: @J.D. - BTree and Binary tree are different.  A trillion rows is 40 deep in a Binary tree, but more like 12 deep in a BTree.  About 14 for a quadrillion.  InnoDB uses BTrees (actually B+Trees -- for helping with range scans).

Comment: @Nuno - 8GB is big enough _if_ you are only touching "recent" rows (or some other "hot spot").  For example, for Inserting "sensor" data, I recommend `PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, datetime)`.  If there are 1K sensors, that is 1K hot spots -- no sweat for 8G of RAM.  And "recent" data for one sensor is clustered together in the B+Tree structure.  Count the blocks needed.

Comment: MariaDB has Columnstore.  But that is a niche market.  Some things going for it:  10x compression of the data, every column automatically indexed, parallel processing (multi-core).

Comment: @RickJames Right, I'm aware of the fan-out factor you're referring to (they're both technically types of BTrees but different implementations). But for simplicity sake I give numbers in the worst case scenario which is the `Log2(n)` search time complexity Bill mentioned, and is still extremely small (seeking through 40 nodes is really no measurably different than see seeking through 12 for modern machines).

Comment: Aggregation -- Build and maintain Summary Table(s) to eliminate the need for big scans of the raw data:  [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Answer (score 10):

> For a billion rows, or for 100 billion rows, is a good Index always better than Partitions, in terms of Performance?

There are several things I can say about this.

- **We can't make this generalization,** because it depends on the query. In general, every kind of optimization is a great help to the right type of query, at the expense of other types of queries. So you must be very specific about which query you want to optimize before choosing the method of optimization.
- **It's not an either-or choice.** You can partition a table, and also define an index, so searches will be optimized in a given partition.
- **I don't think you have 100 billion rows.** If you did, you wouldn't be asking this question on Stack Exchange, you'd be assigning your full-time database architect team the task of optimizing it. They would undoubtedly come back with a design that uses many servers. It's impractical to store 100 billion rows in a single table. How would you back it up? How would you add a column?

InnoDB uses B-tree indexes (also fulltext and spatial indexes, but for this discussion we assume the default type of index).

B-tree indexes have complexity O(log<sub>2</sub>*n*) for both inserting and searching, where *n* is the number of entries in the data structure. Inserting or searching therefore does get more expensive as the index gets larger.

The I/O required by an index search is a function of the *depth* of the B-tree. That is, how many levels of non-terminal nodes must be traversed to get to the leaf node. The depth depends on how many index entries there are, and also depends on how large the data type of a given entry, because InnoDB page sizes are fixed, so only so many index nodes can fit on a page. See:  https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/04/28/the_depth_of_a_b_tree/

I/O cost can be mitigated by keeping subsets of the index pages in RAM, in the InnoDB buffer pool. But if the index grows much larger than RAM, there's not enough buffer pool to hold the whole index, so if you do searches randomly over the whole index, InnoDB is likely to evict pages that you will need again soon. Those pages will be re-loaded from storage when you need them, but this can lead to extra overhead as pages are swapped in and out of RAM.

Caching indexes only applies to MyISAM. InnoDB caches pages on demand, which may include a subset of a given index. Forget about any manual command to load indexes into cache. To be honest, I recommend to forget about MyISAM for any purpose. I haven't seen it used appropriately since the 2000's.

You asked about NVMe storage. NVMe is of course faster than old SATA interfaces, but how does it compare to RAM? It depends what you measure but for both access time and throughput (MB/second) you can count on RAM being several times faster than the latest generation of NVMe. Also the InnoDB code is written to assume that pages must be in RAM before they can be read. It's still a win to keep data and index pages cached in RAM.

I agree with Rick's general statement that partitioning is usually not going to help performance as much as you think it will. It is useful in the right scenario, but it's not a magic "everything go fast" solution. This is true of every other type of optimization too!

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure, I don't have a table with 100B rows, but I have a few with over 1B and growing fairly quickly. So far, I've been scaling vertically, but the conclusion I'm taking from the replies here is that Indexes and Partitions on their own will not resolve the scalability issue. Sharding (scaling horizontally) seems to be where this is heading. Something like Vitess or MariaDB CONNECT, from what I'm researching. This obviously brings a number of other headaches & cons.

Comment: @Nuno I actually disagree with Bill on "*It's impractical to store 100 billion rows in a single table.*". (I do like the rest of the answer though.) There's nothing inherently wrong with storing 100 billion or even 100 trillion rows in a table. It just depends on your use cases. Some people might find that normalizing that data to reduce it in the table is helpful for their particular use cases. But objectively speaking, on its own there's nothing wrong with a table that size and it just depends on how you plan to use it. I didn't have issues with the tables I worked with that approached that.

Comment: @J.D. You have done database operations on a MySQL instance with a table that approached 100 _billion_ rows? Like backups, schema changes, adding indexes when needed, archiving data — not just software development tasks such as writing queries to search it?

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, except on SQL Server not MySQL - but I wouldn't believe MySQL isn't able to handle a table of the same magnitude *almost* just as well. Nightly Full Backups (which keep in mind, the performance of isn't really measured by the number of rows of the table, rather is a factor of the physical size of the table instead), schema changes (which depending on the change can be done online - e.g. adding nullable columns, otherwise applied via alternative solutions to minimize any downtime). We never archived data (hence the big table) but archiving is easy on an indexed table.

Comment: @J.D. Okay that's really great that SQL Server is so capable. MySQL is not. I have supported databases with tables of 1-5 billion rows, and at that scale, it's pretty urgent that the project needs to refactor so they can scale out to multiple database servers. I agree backup time is a function of table size, which varies. But a table that grows over 500GB is starting to get hard to work with. We actually implemented an alert, to urge the developers to either archive some data, or else split up such tables.

Answer (score 5):

> In MySQL/MariaDB, do Indexes' performance degrade as they become larger and larger?

It depends what you mean by "performance"...

If you mean "finding one row or a range of rows based on the indexed key" then the answer would be "a little bit". As the others have explained, as long as the working set of the index remain in cache, "large" may get a little slower than "small", but that is likely to be swamped by the rest of query time used by logistics, network, parsing, etc. If leaf pages are not cached, that would add one random IO, so you'd have to ask your IO system about how long that will take.

But you ask about index vs partitioning, so in this case, if the data is the same in the "partitioned" case and the "single table" case, the total size of indices on partitions would be pretty much the same as the the index on the single table. With the same query load, there's no reason why one would be cached better than the other, so there would likely be no difference between the two. If you access only the latest rows, then both scenarii would benefit in the same way from needing to cache only the corresponding parts of the indices.

However if you take a global view of performance and add stuff like "delete all rows older than 12 months", and you have a billion rows to delete when running this archiving operation, then huge tables and huge indices become an Extremely Bad Idea (TM). If it's an index on date, maybe it will be tolerable because the deletion will hit a contiguous chunk of it. However if it's an index on a rather random column, then every deleted row will trigger random writes somewhere in your index, all over the place, and that will grind forever.

Whereas, if you use partitioning, "DROP PARTITION" is almost instantaneous because behind the scenes, it's just deleting the corresponding files. Unless there are ON DELETE triggers to be fired, there is no point in even reading the rows to delete if the database knows we're dropping the whole partition.

If there are no writes to older partitions, this may make backups a lot faster, if the backup tool can exploit the fact that there is no need to backup a partition that did not change.

I'm editing to add other circumstances when partitioning can make your queries faster:

You don't have enough money to put the whole table on a SSD, so you put the old partitions (and indices) that are seldom accessed on a clunky slow spinning RAID, and the most recent partitions (and indices) that see most of the action on some vert fast SSDs. That's a good "cash vs performance" optimization, but you will have to move partitions once in a while. Maybe you could even replicate just the recent partitions, or put one partition per server and run them in parallel, if the database supports it, stuff like that.

Also if the query optimizer screws it up and decides to do a full table scan or something of the sort, maybe if your table is partitioned and the query has a condition on the partition key, the size of the screwup can be limited to just a few partitions instead of the whole table.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah, I'm aware of the example you gave about purging old data, that Partitions are a very good use for that, versus deleting on a big table. (I appreciate your comment here still) The first 2 paragraphs also make sense, and good to know. Thank you again.